# Need help with Binary Search algorithm error

Tags: algorithm, fortran, binary-search, fortran95

Using the [g95](http://www.g95.org/) compiler, I have an error:

```
Error: Operands of comparison operator '.EQ.' at (1) are LOGICAL(4)/LOGICAL(4)
```

I have no idea what this means. I'm including the subroutine. Do you have any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks so much for your time.

```
  SUBROUTINE search(iarray, ItemSought, Found, Location)
CHARACTER(20), DIMENSION(50),INTENT(IN)::itemarray
CHARACTER(20)::ItemSought
LOGICAL, INTENT(OUT)::Found
INTEGER, INTENT(OUT)::Location
INTEGER:: First, Last, Middle

WRITE(*,'(1x,A)',ADVANCE="NO"),"What are you searching for? "
READ*, ItemSought

First=1
Last=SIZE(Iarray)
FOUND = .FALSE.

DO
    IF ((First > Last) .OR. Found) RETURN
        Middle = (First+Last)/2
    IF (ItemSought < Iarray(Middle)) THEN
        Last=Middle-1
    ELSE IF (ItemSought > Iarray(Middle)) THEN
        First=Middle+1
    ELSE
        Found = .TRUE.
        Location = Middle
    END IF
END DO


IF (Found == .TRUE.) THEN
PRINT*, Itemsought

END SUBROUTINE
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not going to admit the last time I used FORTRAN, but it sure looks a lot different than I remember. So this is just a guess.

Based on the error message I'd say it's on this line (you didn't say which):

```
IF (Found == .TRUE.) THEN
```

Again just guessing, you usually don't test a logical value by comparing to true/false, you use it directly:

```
IF (Found) THEN
```

Answer (score 5):

The `.EQ.` (or `==`)relational operator, just like `.NE.` (`/=`), `.LT.` (`<`) and so on,  is for comparing numbers only, for comparing logical values you should use `.EQV.` and `.NEQV.`